# Scraping data from yahoo finance

Tags: python

I have been trying to scrape data from yahoo finance but every time I try I get the following errors:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Users\nnarn\PycharmProjects\papaproject\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(str(parsePrice()))   
  File "C:\Users\nnarn\PycharmProjects\papaproject\main.py", line 8, in parsePrice
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")   
  File "C:\Users\nnarn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 243, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

The code:

```py
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
def parsePrice():
   r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
   soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")
   price=soup.find('div',{'class':'D(ib) Mend(20px)'})[0].find('span').text
   print(price)
   return price
    
while True:
   print(str(parsePrice()))
```

Answer (score 0):

[BS4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) suggests you use `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')`, as the content of the page you'are downloading is HTML, not XML.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the 'xml', also your `soup.find` contained an error. First `find_all` spans, and then select the one you need from the list:

```
import bs4
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parsePrice():
    r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    price=soup.find('div',{'class':'D(ib) Mend(20px)'}).find_all('span')[0].text
    print(price)
    return price

while True:
    print(str(parsePrice()))
```